# Find non-valid lines from a csv file

Tags: regex

The quotation marks are not matching in the following file.

```
# cat t123.txt
"first", "second", "and last
"second", "line", "ok"
"third", "line", "not, "ok"
```

Only the second line is OK. How do I find the first and third line that do not have consistent quotation marks?

[I have tried this based on an article](https://til.simonwillison.net/bash/skip-csv-rows-with-odd-numbers) that I found. But it does not return the expected results...

https://regex101.com/r/nhDKA2/4

Comment: If there are three fields per line and the quotes are escaped with another quote, you may try `^(?!"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"(?:,\s*"[^"]*(?:""[^"]*)*"){2}$).*`, see https://regex101.com/r/A6XUmM/1

Comment: Using regex for this is dubious anyway. Try a proper CSV parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, your second line is not standard CSV, which does not support a space after the comma.

You can use this regex to test for valid lines based on your CSV spec:

`^(?="[^"]*(", "[^"]*)*"$).*"$`

- `^(?=` ... `)` - positive lookahead at the beginning for:

  - `"[^"]*` - one quote, and anything non-quote
  - `(", "[^"]*)*` - zero or more patterns of `", "...`
  - `"$` - expect `"` at the end
- `.*$"` - whole pattern must end in `"`

Notes on this regex:

- it supports one to many cells
- it does not handle escaped quotes within a cell, such as `"this is a ""quote"" in a cell"`
- it does not support quote-less cells, such as the `99` in `"foo",99,"bar"`, which is valid in CSV

Comment: I changed it to allow zero, one or more spaces after comma. Hope this is correct! ^(?="[^"]*(",[ ]{0,}"[^"]*)*"$).*"$

Comment: That should work. Or a more concise `^(?="[^"]*(", *"[^"]*)*"$).*"$`